# 'Echo' ing an image in php in a div fails

Tags: php, mysql

After Selecting a jpg image from a MySQL server when I try to echo it in a separate division it comes out as a jumble of ascii characters when I use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="image/jpeg; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id = "myDiv">
<h2>Div</h2>
<?php
  require_once('appvars.php');
  require_once('connectvars.php');
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
  $id = 1;
  $query = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE id=?";
  $stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $stmt->bind_result($image);
  $stmt->fetch();
  echo $image;
 ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `echo $image;` works perfectly well. Maybe you should write what you want to ask about? (Perfectly well means that it comes out as a jumble of ASCII characters, so that's correct. If it won't things on your computer would be broken over an acceptable boundary).

Comment: I would wonder if there is html code around the imagepath in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser does not understand that its an image within the "div" where you're echoing.  You'll have to make this PHP script separate and use `<div><img src="/path/to/script.php"></div>`.  That would tell the browser that the content is an image.

Answer (score 2):

Erm... So... are you sending HTML, or an image? You can't send both!

(Well, you can, through a `data:` URL, but that's not greatly supported on older IE)

By the look of it, the only reason you're using HTML is to set the content type header. In which case you just need the PHP:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
```

If you really want to have the image embedded in the HTML, try:

```
echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($image)."\" />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up quiet a lot here. First you have a HTML document with wrong content descriptor. Second you cant just send the raw image data to an HTML document. - You'd need to base64 encode it before.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can't say I'd recommend you store images or other large binary files in a database - you're probably much better off to store them in the filesystem and store the path to them in the DB.

Second, you can't just blurt out the image data in to the middle of the page. You need to use an HTML `<img>` tag. As Kolink says above you can embed the image in the HTML but I wouldn't recommend that as it means it will never be cached. Have the server serve the image at a different URL, and embed it in the page using `<img src="path/to/image" alt="Alternate text here" />`